# Uncaught TypeError: Object {number} has no method 'abort'

Tags: jquery, abort, typeerror

I want to abort a request through `$.ajax()` but I'm keep getting `Uncaught TypeError: Object 5 has no method 'abort'`. The number `5` changes to `10` after one more click and then if you click some more times, it just keeps going up. I am using the following code:

```
var load_info = '';

$('body').on('click', '#moreinfo', function() {
    load_info = setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:'file.php',
            method:"GET",
            success:function(s){ alert(s); },
            error:function(e){ alert(e); }
        })
    },2000);
});

$('body').on('click', '#cancel', function() {
    load_info.abort();
});
```

[Demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edgren/ZL4pm/) (bring up browser's console to see the error)

How can I make this function to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, numbers don't have an `abort` method. Your `load_info` is a number, the handle returned by `setTimeout`. It's not an XHR or jqXHR object.

If you want to cancel the *timer* (prevent the ajax request from being *started*), use:

```
clearTimeout(load_info);
```

If you want to cancel the in-progress ajax call once it is started, you'll have to get the XHR object from `ajax` and then call `abort` on it, like this:

```
var loading_xhr = null;

$('body').on('click', '#moreinfo', function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        loading_xhr = $.ajax({
            url:'file.php',
            method:"GET",
            success:function(s){ alert(s); },
            error:function(e){ alert(e); },
            complete:function(){
                // Be sure to clear it again here
                loading_xhr = null;
            };
        })
    },2000);
});

$('body').on('click', '#cancel', function() {
    if (loading_xhr) {
        loading_xhr.abort();
        loading_xhr = null;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks :) Is `clearTimeout()` and `abort()` the same thing, but `clearTimeout()` just aborts the `setTimeout()`?

Comment: @ErikEdgren: `clearTimeout` and `abort` are unrelated. `clearTimout` clears the scheduled timer. If you call it before the timer fires, the function you've scheduled won't run. In this case, that means you'll never call `$.ajax`. `abort` is for aborting XHR requests that are in progress.

Answer (score 0):

[setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout) returns a **number**:

> the numerical ID of the timeout, which can be used later with
>   window.clearTimeout().

```
>>> var x = window.setTimeout(function(){}, 1000)
undefined
>>> x
102
>>> typeof x
"number"
```

I suspect you want what the documentation suggests:

```
window.clearTimeout(load_info);
```